# initMap is not a function (ASP/NET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have js script file. Where I use google heatmap

Here is code of js file

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //map initialization
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            {
                zoom: 5,
                center: { lat: 51.0742853, lng: 11.0294547 },
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });
        var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var centerControlDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
        var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);
        var centerControl2 = new CenterControl1(centerControlDiv, map);

        centerControlDiv.index = 1;
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
        getDriving();
    }
    });
```

In View I have script

```
script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCea6mL2cqwVid2ESIjuJ0C31RbNVQNPY0&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
```

When I run project I have  `initMap is not a function` error. How I can fix it.

Delete `callback=initMap` not solve problem

Here is how scripts defined

```
  <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCea6mL2cqwVid2ESIjuJ0C31RbNVQNPY0&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
</script>

<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.2/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Datepicker-Languages/datepicker-languages.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Styles/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-ui-extensions/weekMonthDatepicker.js?v=1.0.0.0"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/Reports/Heatmap.js"></script>
```

InitMap in this row `<script src="~/Scripts/Reports/Heatmap.js"></script>`

Comment: Do you define initMap in your View before you try to use it? Javascript code MUST come BEFORE any references to it.

Comment: I updated my post@RobAnthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the async, which tells the Browser to parse the code independently of the rest of the code being loaded and just rely on the defer, which tells the browser to wait until the document is loaded until executing it.

```
  <script defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCea6mL2cqwVid2ESIjuJ0C31RbNVQNPY0&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
```

OR change the order of the scripts in the file to:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Reports/Heatmap.js"></script>
<script async
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCea6mL2cqwVid2ESIjuJ0C31RbNVQNPY0&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

You also don't need to wait for the document to load (and don't want to) to define your function so remove the first and last lines.

```
   //map initialization
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            {
                zoom: 5,
                center: { lat: 51.0742853, lng: 11.0294547 },
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });
        var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var centerControlDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
        var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);
        var centerControl2 = new CenterControl1(centerControlDiv, map);

        centerControlDiv.index = 1;
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
        getDriving();
    }
```

Comment: You ONLY need to put javascript in $(document).ready(function() if you need the whole DOM to load before you execute a piece of code. As you are only defining a function, you do not need to do this. You usually need to make sure the DOM is loaded when you are modifying or reading the DOM in some way but you aren't here, so you can get rid of the $(document).ready.. lines